# How do I implement a camera for a canvas using Scrollviewers / something similar

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, scrollviewer

I need a "camera" which is able to show a canvas **from different viewports at once**.
My first idea was to simply use 2 different scrollviewers and give both of them the same canvas as content and simply changing the amount of scroll in both of them.

Unfortunately only one scrollview displays the content, the other one is empty. The strange thing here is that the order in which you add the scrollview to the root element (which is also a canvas in this case) decides which one gets the content, rather than the order in which you add the contents to the scrollviewers.

So is it possible to use scrollviewers for my purpose somehow? If now, do you have any suggestion on how implement a simple camera that is capable of having 2 different viewports on the same Canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Here's some really bad code I made for testing:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    Canvas _root = new Canvas();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _root = new Canvas();
        AddChild(_root);

        //ScrollViewer 1
        ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
        sv.Height = 400;
        sv.Width = 600;

        //ScrollerViewer 2
        ScrollViewer sv2 = new ScrollViewer();
        sv2.Height = 400;
        sv2.Width = 200;

        // Will be set later as Content of both Scrollviewers
        Canvas svc = new Canvas();
        svc.Width = Width;
        svc.Height = Height;
        svc.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));

        // rectangle to be displayed on the canvas 
        Canvas rect = new Canvas();
        rect.Height = 100;
        rect.Width = 100;
        rect.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));


        sv2.Content = svc;
        sv.Content = svc;

        // Add the scrollviews to the root canvas.
        // !!! The order you add them decides (somehow?) which scrollview gets the content.
        _root.Children.Add(sv);
        _root.Children.Add(sv2);

        svc.Children.Add(rect);


        Canvas.SetLeft(sv, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(sv2, 900);

    }
}
```

Comment: You simply need 2 contents, normal one and zoomed version. `FrameworkElement` can has only one parent, therefore your idea of *sharing* canvas won't work.

Comment: That would be really bad since there is a lot of stuff going on my canvas and computing the position for every element 2 times is really unefficent. Is there any camera-like feature in wpf I could use?

Comment: You can use the same `RenderTargetBitmap` for multiple `Image` elements. So one obvious approach would be to have your "shared `Canvas`" not be in the visual graph at all; instead, maintain it independently, and when its visual appearance changes, render it into the `RenderTargetBitmap` that is being used for your viewports.

Comment: If don't need interaction (e.g. hit testing) then idea of @PeterDuniho should do the trick: content (`Canvas`) is presented through `Image` *snapshots* (your *cameras*). Otherwise you better switch to MVVM before it's too late: Model will hold all primitives data while 2 Views (*cameras* - `ContentControls`) will present same shared ViewModel data in different ways (one is normal and second is zoomed).

Comment: @Sinatr: quite right. I really should have mentioned that before diving in with a literal solution of the stated problem. I made the assumption that the OP had considered and rejected such an approach for some reason, but in reflection that was a silly assumption for me to make.  I hope that I have sufficiently rectified all that with my edit to my answer (I figure there's no need to go deeply into the templating approach, since it's fundamental to WPF and there exists plenty of tutorials/examples/etc. for that already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I agree with commenter Sinatr's point that it would be better to just use data templating with view models, if possible. You can have a single view model that is used as the context for two or more `ContentControl` objects that simply present that view model using whatever `DataTemplate` is defined for it. This will allow full user interaction, highest quality rendering, and the most flexible approach (i.e. your different "cameras" could even present radically different visuals for the same data, depending on your needs).

Here is an example of how that would look:

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        x:Name="mainWindow1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel Text="Some Text"/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:ViewModel}">
      <Canvas Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=mainWindow1}"
              Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainWindow1}"
              Background="Yellow">
        <Canvas Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
        <!--
            I added text and a button, so that the view model actually
            _does_ something, but you could use an empty view model class
            and leave out the Grid here and it would work just as well.
        -->
        <Grid Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=mainWindow1}"
              Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainWindow1}">
          <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="32"/>
            <Button Content="Reverse" Command="{Binding Command}" FontSize="24"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
      </Canvas>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Canvas>
    <ScrollViewer Width="600" Height="400"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Width="200" Height="400" Canvas.Left="900"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ICommand _command;
    private string _text = string.Empty;

    public ICommand Command { get { return _command; } }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text != value)
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _command = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecuteCommand);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteCommand(object parameter)
    {
        Text = new string(Text.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}

class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _handler;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> handler) : this(handler, null) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> handler, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _handler((T)parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

My answer below is intended to address the specific question you asked, in the context provided. It assumes you have some good reason for building up the UI this way and that literally explicitly creating separate object graphs for each "camera" is undesirable for some reason (maybe a performance issue? though, I would expect WPF to optimize perf as well as you or I could). But I was remiss in not addressing the elephant in the room, vis-à-vis the ability for normal WPF idioms to solve this scenario more elegantly than actually trying to build up two different "cameras" of the same visual. I hope that the above alternative gives you some context with which to evaluate your options.

With that said…

You can use the same `RenderTargetBitmap` for multiple `Image` elements. So one obvious approach would be to have your "shared `Canvas`" not be in the visual graph at all; instead, maintain it independently, and when its visual appearance changes, render it into the `RenderTargetBitmap` that is being used for your viewports.

Here is a "really bad code" example (i.e. based on your original above :p) that shows what I mean:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Canvas _root = new Canvas();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _root = new Canvas();
        AddChild(_root);

        //ScrollViewer 1
        ScrollViewer sv = new ScrollViewer();
        sv.Height = 400;
        sv.Width = 600;

        //ScrollerViewer 2
        ScrollViewer sv2 = new ScrollViewer();
        sv2.Height = 400;
        sv2.Width = 200;

        // Will be set later as Content of both Scrollviewers
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Width = Width;
        canvas.Height = Height;
        canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));

        // rectangle to be displayed on the canvas 
        Canvas rect = new Canvas();
        rect.Height = 100;
        rect.Width = 100;
        rect.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        canvas.Children.Add(rect);
        canvas.Measure(new Size(Width, Height));
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));

        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Width, (int)Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        bitmap.Render(canvas);

        sv.Content = new Image { Source = bitmap };
        sv2.Content = new Image { Source = bitmap };
        sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        sv2.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;

        _root.Children.Add(sv);
        _root.Children.Add(sv2);

        Canvas.SetLeft(sv, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(sv2, 900);
    }
}
```

Note that since the `Canvas` object isn't part of the visual tree, you have to act as the host for it yourself by calling `Measure()` and `Arrange()` so that it correctly initializes its children for rendering.

Alternatively, you could provide the `Canvas` object as the `Content` for *one* `ScrollViewer`, and then use the `RenderTargetBitmap` object in the others. In this case, you won't need to call `Measure()` and `Arrange()` yourself, but you *will* need to make sure you don't try to render the bitmap until the framework has done that. For example, instead of calling `bitmap.Render(canvas);` in the constructor as above, call it in a handler for the `Loaded` event:

```
        Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            bitmap.Render(canvas);
        };
```

In either case, it will be up to you to detect when the bitmap needs to be re-rendered. This could involve a fair amount of work, depending on how complex your rendering is. If all you ever do is add/remove children, the responding to the `LayoutUpdated` event on the rendered `Canvas` object might be sufficient. If you need to respond to smaller changes, such as a change in color of a sub-element, you might need to actually sub-class `Canvas` and hook into appropriate event(s); e.g. override the `OnRender()` method and call the bitmap's `Render()` method when the `base.OnRender()` has returned.

Comment: Thanks a lotI for the reply. I'm basically having a tile based game with a lot of entitys moving the entire time. The camera is supposed to "follow" a certain entity, but I need several cameras following different entitys. Since everything is constantly moving, I need to constantly re-render the entire state of the game. I guess your method might be too ressource heavy to re-render it every few miliseconds, isn't it? (16ms to be correct)

Comment: Games have very different priorities than most any other kind of program. Whether performance would be high enough for your needs using the straight MVVM idiom, I can't say...for sure the simple example above should easily be able to render at 60fps. But more complicated scenarios, maybe not. Depends on the scenario. At least as big an issue for you will be getting smooth frame rates at that speed, just because of the way thread scheduling works in Windows.

Comment: In any case, if the MVVM approach is too slow, `RenderTargetBitmap` is probably the next thing to try, but you will have to re-render the bitmap from scratch every frame, bypassing WPF's own optimizations. It's not a sure thing that it will net you a big enough performance gain to warrant it. It also depends on just how many of these "cameras" you expect to have. Two or three, I would think MVVM could keep up easily. Dozens, and I'd guess a bitmap buffer would be needed. Neither technique is guaranteed to solve whatever performance issue you have.